# Spring Boot encapsulating form-data using @ModelAttribute annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

## Background and Context

I have a Spring Boot application that runs as an executable JAR in an embedded Tomcat container.  The application exposes a variety of traditional RESTful services.  In addition to the the traditional RESTful services I also need to create an endpoint that is more similar to a traditional servlet.

> I define *Traditional RESTful services* as endpoints that use standard HTTP methods ( GET, POST, PUT, etc ) and accept JSON or XML request bodies ( when applicable method is used ) and returns JSON or XML.  I define *traditional* in contrast with servlet-like endpoints that accept multipart/form-date and redirect the client after the method is called.

This endpoint signature is as follows

1. Accepts a multipart/form-data
2. POST method
3. Redirects users to the base url of the value assigned to the `referer` header after submission

The form data sent to this endpoint is sent from a form that I do not own or control ( I have included the html form below ).  Because the form has many oddly named key/value pairs I want to encapsulate the submission in a `FormSubmission` object.

## Code

Below is the form used to send data to my endpoint

```
<form novalidate="" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://baseurl.com/brochure" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hsForm_4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" method="POST" class="hs-form stacked hs-form-private hs-form-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5_bc44b3dd-63e5-4a6f-85d2-4c2c4b436bf8" data-form-id="4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" data-portal-id="482700" target="target_iframe_4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0">
   <input id="firstname-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" type="text" name="firstname"></div>
   <input id="lastname-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" type="text" name="lastname"></div>
   <input id="address-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" type="text" name="address"></div>
   <select id="state-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" name="state" >
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="" >- Please Select -</option>
      <option value="AL" >Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
   </select>
   <select id="country_custom-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5"  name="country_custom" ">
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   </select>
   <input id="zip-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" class="hs-input" type="text" name="zip"></div>
   <input id="email-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" class="hs-input" type="email" name="email"></div>
   <select id="want_to_talk_with_an_area_builder_-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" name="want_to_talk_with_an_area_builder_">
      <option value="Yes">Yes, now please.</option>
      <option value="No">No thank you</option>
   </select>
   <select id="blog_pool_life_2_subscription-4b5eec88-e83b-474f-9c51-6204df71e5a5" name="blog_pool_life_2_subscription"
      <option value="instant">Instant</option>
      <option value="daily">Daily</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

The above form sends multipart/form-data to the following endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/brochure")
public RedirectView post( @ModelAttribute FormSubmission submission, RedirectAttributes attributes, @RequestHeader( value = "referer", required = true ) final String referer ) {

    String base = getBaseURL( referer );

    System.out.println( submission.getLastName() );

    return new RedirectView( base );
}
```

And the FormSubmission class is as follows

```
public class FormSubmission {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private Boolean mail;
    private String speakWithBuilder;

    @ModelAttribute("city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("city")
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("state")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("state")
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("zip")
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("zip")
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("country_custom")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("country_custom")
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("country_custom")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("country_custom")
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("blog_pool_life_2_subscription")
    public Boolean isMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("blog_pool_life_2_subscription")
    public void setMail( String mail ) {
        this.mail = mail.toLowerCase().contains( "yes" );
    }

    @ModelAttribute("firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("firstname")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("lastname")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("address")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("address")
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("want_to_talk_with_an_area_builder_")
    public String getSpeakWithBuilder() {
        return speakWithBuilder;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("want_to_talk_with_an_area_builder_")
    public void setSpeakWithBuilder(String speakWithBuilder) {
        this.speakWithBuilder = speakWithBuilder;
    }


}
```

## Problem Statement

As you can see my endpoint defines a `@ModelAttribute FormSubmission submission`, and my submission object notates each getter and setter with the name of elements from the HTML form.  However, the print statements show as null.  I swore that this was working a few days ago, and now all values are null.  Please advice.

## Post Script #1

For additional clarification, when I modify my endpoint signature as follows

```
@PostMapping("/brochure")
public RedirectView post( @ModelAttribute("firstname") String firstName, RedirectAttributes attributes, @RequestHeader( value = "referer", required = true ) final String referer ) {

    System.out.println( firstName );
    String base = getBaseURL( referer );


    return new RedirectView( base );
}
```

And call the endpoint the first name does print successfully.  I hope this better illustrates that my question is specifically about encapsulating these form data key/value pairs inside an object.

## Post Script #2

I was able to successfully encapsulate the data if I:

1. Remove `@ModelAttribute` from the FormSubmission parameter, and
2. Remove the `@ModelAttribute` from the getter and setter methods for the private member variables inside FormSubmission

This is better but I would still like to be able to name by variables consistent with Java's naming convention which I cannot do without ModelAttribute since I do not control the form

Comment: I have the same problem, I got that object but is empty. [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-can-i-upload-files-to-a-server-using-jsp-servlet?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)